# new to javascript- image gallery- thumbnails expand to full size when selected

Tags: javascript, image, thumbnails

[work in progress- live site](http://parlourdc.com/wp/gallery)

I have a gallery page with several sub-pages. Each sub-page has a row of thumbnails on the left. When one of the thumbnails is selected, it will show larger on the right. This is a Wordpress site, but I've been told that JS might be the best route to take. I'm fairly inexperienced with JS, so I'm unsure of how to go about this.

How do I go about showing the thumbnails and the selected image?

Comment: Will you be using different images for thumbnail and large one?

Comment: @sogeek     My initial thought was for each thumbnail will be different, and the large image will be the thumbnail the user has clicked on. But, needless to say, I'm open to suggestions- whatever will be easiest and most effective.

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery?

Comment: I'm not. @Charles provided a link to a tutorial site, though which seems like it may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of jQuery ([jQuery is very powerful!!](http://jquery.com)) gallery plugins can do what you need. Check out this awesome site [awesome jQuery tutorials](http://tympanus.net/codrops/category/tutorials/page/6/), there are many detailed tutorials about how to build inspiring image gallery.

Except JS/jQuery, you also need to know how to use Html && CSS.

The basic idea is show/hide(static or load by ajax dynamically) your big image when `hover()` your thumbnails.